Weld not detecting @Inject with Jetty 12, Java 21 and Apache Wicket
I am trying to setup a small application with Jetty, Apache Wicket and Java 21 but it seems like my Weld DI is not picking up on the injection decorators (@Inject and @RequestScoped):
My setup is a default Wicket (maven) Quickstart (from wicket.apache.org) modified to support Java21 and ee10.
pom.xml dependency versions:
    // [...] pom.xml stuff

    <properties>
        <wicket.version>10.1.0</wicket.version>
        <slf4j.version>2.0.13</slf4j.version>
        <jetty.version>12.0.7</jetty.version>
        <junit.version>5.10.2</junit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- allowed values: R7, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 or none -->
        <wtp.version>none</wtp.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--  WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-native-websocket-javax</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-ee10-websocket-jakarta-server</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.ee10</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-ee10-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

               // [...] more pom.xml stuff

And my Start.java:
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("wicket.configuration", "development");

        Server server = new Server();

        HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
        httpConfig.setSecureScheme("https");
        httpConfig.setSecurePort(8443);
        httpConfig.setOutputBufferSize(32768);

        ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
        http.setPort(8080);
        http.setIdleTimeout(1000 * 60 * 60);

        server.addConnector(http);

        WebAppContext bb = new WebAppContext();
        bb.setServer(server);
        bb.setContextPath("/");
        bb.setWar("src/main/webapp");

        bb.addEventListener(new Listener());  // supposedly the wicket-cdi injection?

        ServletContextHandler contextHandler = ServletContextHandler.getServletContextHandler(bb.getServletContext());
        JakartaWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(contextHandler,
                (servletContext, container) -> container.addEndpoint(new WicketServerEndpointConfig()));

        server.setHandler(bb);

        MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        MBeanContainer mBeanContainer = new MBeanContainer(mBeanServer);
        server.addEventListener(mBeanContainer);
        server.addBean(mBeanContainer);

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(100);
        }
    }

The error I am getting is:
org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.ReflectionDiscoveryStrategy processAnnotatedDiscovery
INFO: WELD-ENV-000014: Falling back to Java Reflection for bean-discovery-mode="annotated" discovery. Add org.jboss:jandex to the classpath to speed-up startup.
org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle initialize
INFO: WELD-ENV-001001: No supported servlet container detected, CDI injection will NOT be available in Servlets, Filters or Listeners
[INFO] Session workerName=node0
[INFO] Started oeje10mp.MavenWebAppContext@1f10fec6{tractorStore,/,b=file://my-app/src/main/webapp/,a=AVAILABLE,h=oeje10s.SessionHandler@144e36ae{STARTED}}{file://my-app/src/main/webapp/}
org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener contextInitialized
INFO: WELD-ENV-001006: org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener used to initialize Weld
org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener contextInitialized
INFO: WELD-ENV-001009: org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener used for ServletRequest and HttpSession notifications
[main] INFO org.apache.wicket.util.file.WebXmlFile - web.xml: url mapping found for filter with name wicket.tractorStore: [/*]
[main] INFO org.apache.wicket.Application - [wicket.tractorStore] init: Wicket core library initializer
[main] INFO org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication - [wicket.tractorStore] Started Wicket version 10.1.0 in DEVELOPMENT mode

and during runtime all my @Inject classes remain null (they contain the @Named and @RequestScoped decorators).
I suspect it has something to do with:
INFO: WELD-ENV-001001: No supported servlet container detected, CDI injection will NOT be available in Servlets, Filters or Listeners
Is there anything I am missing? I have no idea what to include in my Start.java
Thanks in advance!
Edit: Never mind I found the right solution

Add a beans.xml in your WEB-INF folder:

<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>


Add this in your WicketApplication.java

        CdiConfiguration cdiConfiguration = new CdiConfiguration();
        cdiConfiguration.configure(this);


Glad to hear you found the solution, and thanks for sharing it
